# Apache2 site configuration / document root and sub-sites

Tags: apache, configuration, apache2

In the directory `/var/www` I have the following directories: `foo`, `bar` and `baz`. I want `foo` to be my document root, that is, when `www.example.com/` is requested, the directory `/var/www/foo` is served. Otherwise, for all other directories, `/var/www/` is considered to be document root, so `www.example.com/bar/` serves `/var/www/bar/` and `www.example.com/baz/` shows `/var/www/baz`.

I could set the document root to `/var/www/foo/` and move the directories `bar` and `baz` there, which I don't want to do. The server has a main purpose and a few other, unrelated tasks which are contained in these additional directories. I don't want to mix this.

I can set the document root to `/var/www/foo` and use the `Alias` directive to map the other directories to the required locations, so in the case above

```
Alias /bar /var/www/bar
Alias /baz /var/www/baz
```

However, each time that I add another directory, I would have to modify the apache configuration.

Is there a better way?